# Java-Sockets: How to send and serialize object between multiple applications

Tags: java, class, sockets, serversocket, object-serialization

I have 2 maven applications that should communicate via server socket and socket. If possible, I want to send the data as a Java-object, but for that I need both of those projects to include the class of the object.

If possible, I don't want to make a third maven project with the class and add it to the server and client project as a dependency. Is there any other way to do that?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: "but for that I need both of those projects to include the class of the object" - It sounds like you already have your answer.

Comment: Java native serialization is ridden of problems anyway. There's a reason why everyone use JSON or possibly XML instead.

Comment: @JacobG. So should I just copy the file? Just implement serializable, ad serial version did and copy the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your server project a sub-project of your client project, meaning that your server has access to all the classes the client needs, plus some extras.

Alternatively, you can create a JAR containing shared classes, and install this to your local (or remote if you have access) maven repository, using `mvn install` (docs here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

For the actual transfer of data, you could serialize your objects using the `Serializable` interface, however there are many issues with this approach:

- Fragile to class changes - if you change your class, old objects will likely break unless you manually manage this
- Java-only - you will not be able to, for example, write your client in C++ and your server in Java, if you ever decide to do something similar.
- Framework incompatibility - many popular frameworks work primarily with other formats, and cannot guarantee compatibility.

Instead, you can use:

- JSONs - Using Jackson Databind, or Google Gson libraries, they are flexible, powerful and standardised
- XML - Similar to JSONs, with some subtle differences
- Google Protobuf - Also has some limitations but very underrated for resource-constrained environments.
- Custom String Format - implement your own `toDataString()` and `fromDataString()` methods. This is only really feasible for small classes, as there are many issues with Unicode, escape characters, encodings etc that most libraries hide from you. This is more risky than other methods.

In general, I would reccomend JSON unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. I personally use Jackson, here is a link to a tutorial: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: So if I use Jackson, I still have to make the server project a sub project of the client project, right?

Comment: Correct. When recieving a message from a socket, you must provide `Message.class` (or whatever your message class is called). There are ways to parse JSONs without having access to the class, but you should include the sources, as it is good design

Comment: Sorry for another question, but can I really use the parent project as a normal module, because the packaging has to be pom and not jar